# The best approach using part of an interface in another interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, interface

I have a project with nextjs and typescript. I have two interfaces like below

```js
export interface IAccordion {
    accordionItems: {
        id: string | number;
        title: string | React.ReactElement;
        content: string | React.ReactElement;
    }[];
    isMultiple?: boolean;
    className?: string;
    itemClassName?: string;
}

export interface IAccordionItem
    extends Pick<IAccordion, 'isMultiple' | 'itemClassName'> {
    accordionItem: IAccordion['accordionItems'][0];
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

in IAccordionItem I have accordionItem property that is like the accordionItems property in IAccordion but it is a single object I want to khow is this line of code

```
 accordionItem: IAccordion['accordionItems'][0];
```

the best option that I have

Comment: You can use `accordionItem: IAccordion['accordionItems'][number];` too. Not sure which is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You approach with Items[0] is a working one. The suggested Items[number] will also work. Alternatively I would suggest extracting the reusable entities into its own type/interface with a human readable name. This way it will be easier to reuse and maintain. now and later if needed.

```js
interface AccordionItem {
    id: string | number;
    title: string | React.ReactElement;
    content: string | React.ReactElement;
}

export interface IAccordion {
    accordionItems: AccordionItem[];
    isMultiple?: boolean;
    className?: string;
    itemClassName?: string;
}

export interface IAccordionItem
    extends Pick<IAccordion, 'isMultiple' | 'itemClassName'> {
    accordionItem: AccordionItem;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```